# Find 2 subsets in array that have minimum difference and consecutive elements

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, knapsack-problem, subset-sum

I came across a variation of the subset sum problem that i find quite interesting. So, given an array of (positive) elements, you have to partition it in 2 sets so that their difference is minimum. But here is the catch. The elements have to be consecutive and they also work in circular order. Here are 2 examples so you can understand what I mean:

EXAMPLE 1:

INPUT: 7 5 1 3 8 9 11 8

OUTPUT:  0  ( set 1: {11,8,7},set 2: {5,1,3,8,9}

[image: result picture].

---

EXAMPLE 2:

INPUT:10 14 75 90 3 5 40 4 8

OUTPUT: 27 (set 1: {4,8,10,14,75},set 2: {90,3,5,40})

What is a possible solution using C++? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is **linear-time solution** using two-pointer approach. Target parameter is range with sum as close to the sum of the rest as possible.

Set both indexes `left, right` into array beginning. `csum` is current sum of array range `left..right-1`.

If adding one more element makes current cum closer to ideal one, move right index and update parameters.

When adding element makes current sum worse, start to remove left elements.

Delphi code returns only the best difference, range itself (`(left,right-1)` pair) might be found in own implementation of `Min` operation.

```
  function Nice(A: TArray<Integer>): Integer;
  var
    left, right, i, sum, csum, diff: Integer;
  begin
    sum := 0;
    for i := 0 to High(A) do
        sum := sum + A[i];

    left := 0;
    right := 1;
    csum := A[0]; //sum of current subsequence
    diff := Abs(sum - 2 * csum); //dif = Abs((sum - csum) - csum)
    result := diff;

    repeat

      //if adding right element makes difference better
      while (right < Length(A)) and (Abs(sum - 2 * (csum + A[right])) < diff) do begin
        csum := csum + A[right];
        diff := Abs(sum - 2 * csum);
        result := Min(result, diff);
        right := right + 1;
      end;

      repeat
        csum := csum - A[left];  //we always need at least one step
        diff := Abs(sum - 2 * csum);
        result := Min(result, diff);
        left := left + 1;
      until (left = right) or (Abs(sum - 2 * (csum - A[left])) >= diff);

    until (left = right);

  end;
```

Comment: Thx a lot for your time! Is this gonna be more efficient if we use a dynamic programming approach instead of a straight-forward solution?

Comment: This method has the best possible efficiency. It might be considered as kind of DP - imagine filling of some trajectory in left/right table

Comment: Ok, i've encountered a  bug though, the program returns 14 as the optimal difference for the second set, but the answer is 27. any ideas?

Comment: @dituoa function finds optimization parameter 14 as difference of halfsum 124 and 90..40 subsequence sum 138. The rest has sum 111, so 138-111=27. I'll write correction to return value you need